# How to retrieve the word before space from text widget of tkinter each time space is pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox

I am trying to retrieve the word before  everytime space is entered. For example, If a user types " iam a" i want to retrieve "iam" and then if user types "iam a girl" i want to retrieve "a" .

Following is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)  

        lsum = tk.Label(self,borderwidth=2,text="suggestions")
        lsum.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky=tk.W)


        def func3():
            contents = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)
            lsum["text"] = contents



        def func4():
            self.text.bind("<space>",func3())





        self.text= tk.Text(self, height=5, width=30,borderwidth=2)
        self.text.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=4)
        self.text.insert(tk.END, "")



        self.v = tk.IntVar()
        self.d = tk.IntVar()
        self.e = tk.IntVar()
        self.radio1=tk.Radiobutton(self, text="آيک گرآم مآڈل ", variable=self.v, value=1,command=func2).grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2)
        self.radio2=tk.Radiobutton(self, text="دو گرآم مآڈل ", variable=self.d, value=2,command=func3).grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=2)
        self.radio3=tk.Radiobutton(self, text="تین گرآم مآڈل", variable=self.e, value=3).grid(column=0,row=3,columnspan=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    run = ExampleApp()
    run.mainloop()
```

Kindly Help please.

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything? Also, please reduce this down to a [mcve]. If the question is about finding a word before the cursor, we don't need the radio buttons, intvars, or the label.

Comment: radio button is to call that function.

Comment: Ye sit is like finding a word before the cursor. Can you guide me please

Comment: Why do you need three radiobuttons for the purpose of this question? Everything you need to know is documented here, among other places: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand what you're asking (which is tricky enough) you can call `.bind()` on the `Text` widget with the event being `"<space>"`.

This would look something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def callback(*args):
    print(text.get("1.0", END).split(" ")[len(text.get("1.0", END).split(" "))-1])

text.bind("<space>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

This means that everytime the space key is pressed in the `Text` widget we get a callback which prints the word you're looking for in the widget.